# extract single attribute from SQL SERVER stored procedure in powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

Currently I am facing this issue:

I have a table in SQL Server that has 4 columns and I am using powershell to extract the data

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx,1433;Initial Catalog=DB;User Id=User; Password=password;"
$sqlCommand="dbo.sp_sel_hailGU"
$connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)


$command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlCommand, $connection)
$command.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure

# $parameter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter ("@TradeDateParam", $tradeDate)
$command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImgName", $ImgName) | Out-Null 

$adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command

$connection.Open()   
$adapter.Fill($result) | Out-Null
$connection.Close()

return $result.Tables
```

This code shows all the values from the table in the following format

```
attribute1: value1
attribute2: value22
attribute3: value33
attribute4: value44

attribute1: value2
attribute2: value222
attribute3: value333
attribute4: value444
```

However, what I want to do in Powershell is to get the value of each attribute in a separate way and assign them to a Powershell variable in order to make some data treatment

I tried to make a pipeline to the variable trying to get the attributes but to no avail

Any help will be appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can output the value of an object, using dot notation.

```
$var.Access.IdentityReference
```

or this..

```
$($var.Access).IdentityReference
```

As for this...

> get the value of each attribute in a separate way ...

what does this mean?

If you mean to separate these two value items from each other...

```
attribute1: value1
attribute2: value22
attribute3: value33
attribute4: value44

attribute1: value2
attribute2: value222
attribute3: value333
attribute4: value444
```

...

You can split on the ':' and select the proper position you want.

```
$DBValues = @'
    attribute1: value1
    attribute2: value22
    attribute3: value33
    attribute4: value44

    attribute1: value2
    attribute2: value222
    attribute3: value333
    attribute4: value444
'@

$DBValues -split ': '
```

Or pick out the value using RegEx ...
Example:

```
# Grab the string value based on the match
[regex]::Matches($DBValues,'\svalue.*').Value

# Grab the string value after the match
[regex]::Matches($DBValues,'(?<=attribute.*[:]\s).*?(?=\s)').Value
```

As for this ...

> assign them to a Powershell variable

... you cannot pipeline data unless you set that up in your script in

```
param
(
  [Parameter(mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$InputObject,
  [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]$FileName
)
...
```